# Python / Selenium - How to click on empty space (safest way)

Tags: python, selenium

When I add value to an input element, I need to deselect it so it will be updated and the page will be refreshed (so I can interact with other elements)

Currently I know two ways of clicking on empty space:

- `ActionChains(b).send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()`
- `b.find_element_by_xpath("//body").click()`

Clicking the body works the best, BUT on rare occasions, clicking the body will click something (overlays) that causes issues.

Sending TAB works perfect, BUT it might cause issues as when bot tabbing to the next element drop-down could appear.

**Question:** Is there another **SAFE** way to de-select elements (by clicking on the white space) which will cause no issues?

- E.g. something along the line of checking not interactable place on the page and click it :D